# Turn content in a file into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.3

I want to return a dictionary that a file contains. What I have is this code:

```
def read_report(filename):
    new_report = {}
    input_filename = open(filename)
    for line in input_filename:
        lines = line[:-1]
        new_report.append(lines)
    input_filename.close()
    return new_report
```

It says I can't append to a dictionary. So how would I go with adding lines from the file into the dictionary? Let's say my filename is this:

```
shorts: a, b, c, d
longs: a, b, c, d
mosts: a
count: 11
avglen: 1.0

a 5
b 3
c 2
d 1
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean "a dictionary that a file contains"? You have shown the file contents, what do you expect as output from the function?

Comment: I wouldn't bring it up except you've made this mistake on multiple questions now: a filename is the *name* of a file (reasonably enough), and in Python that would typically be a string.  This isn't the same as the file itself.  `input_filename` isn't a filename.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I expect the output to be a dictionary. so everything in the file comes out as a dictionary with the keys as: shorts, longs, mosts, etc and the values as ["a", "b", "c", "d"] etc

Comment: @DSM soo should I change input_filename.close() to filename.close()??

Comment: it would be good to put the sample text file you want to read!

Comment: @san the sameple text is there!

Comment: `new_report[line[0:1]] = line[:-1]`?

Comment: Do you want your output to be?: `new_report = {'shorts': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'longs: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'mosts': 'a', 'count': 11, 'avglen': 1.0, 'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 1}`

Comment: why you choose to use dictionary why you need a list? Just change new_report = [] instead of new_report = {}, it will be ok.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl  yes but I would want it to look like the file in that each one prints in a new line but in dictionary format

Answer (score 0):

if you rewrite your input file to have uniform lines like the first and the second, you could try this:

EDIT: modified code to support also lines with space separator instead of colon (:)

```
def read_report(filename):
    new_report = {}
    f = open(filename)
    for line in f:
        if line.count(':') == 1:
            key, value = line.split(':')
        else:
            key, value = line.split(' ')
        new_report[key] = value.split(',')
    f.close()
    return new_report
```

Comment: I don't think you can iterate over the file object.

Comment: You can iterate over a file object.

Comment: I get a Value Error and that it needs more than one value to unpack

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That is amazing. I learned something new today. You can iterate over the file object! But why do you have methods like `read` then?

Comment: @user2976821 add ':' to the lines that don't have

Comment: @AndreiBoyanov and what if some files don't have ":" .

Comment: It will be better if you define the format of the input file. How are keys separated from values? With ' :',  with ' '  (space)  or both are possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the last lines of your files (the ones that don't contain `:`) are to be ignored.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      if ':' in line:
          key, val = line.split(':')
          d[key.strip()] += val.rstrip().split(',')
```

Comment: can I use setdefualt function rather than importing?

Comment: Sure. `d.setdefault(key.strip(), []) += val.rstrip().split(',')`

Comment: it gives me a sytnax error and that it can't assign to function call

Comment: Where does it give you that?

Comment: remove the `.strip()` from `key.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_line(filename):
    list = [] 
    new_report = {} 
    file_name = open(filename)
    for i in file_name:
        list.append(i[:-1])
    for i in range(len(list)):
        new_report[i] = list[i]
    file_name.close()
    return new_report
```